# How to change value of a field in hook_node_view

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

In `hook_node_view()` I want to rewrite some fields' values. The `$node` parameter is not referenced, so how can I rewrite a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the API documentation for [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), specifically the comments at the end of the page -> [Has anyone been able to successfully modify a node object?](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7#comment-16954). There's talk of using [hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) as a solution as well as many of the hooks that are field specific. Note the comments at the bottom of the hook_node_load API page that explains why $nodes is not called by reference but is still changed when changes are made to the variable within the hook re: OOP -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php.

Comment: In the hook I enter `$node = array()` but the node is loaded completely with all fields. Why?

Comment: I also implemented hook_field_load and hook_field_prepare_view but they don't seem to be called.(Tested with `exit()` command in hook function body!)

Answer (score 3):

Clear the cache or visit the Modules page to get the hook picked up after you've added it to your module. Then something like this will work.

```
function my_module_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {  
  switch($node->type) {
    case 'foo':
      $node->content['field_my_field'][0]['#markup'] = 'Changed!';  
    break;  
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the changed value is not showing only the original. When I check with dpm the node I can see the value updated, but still the old value is shown to the user. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by implementing template_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) in your template.php

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    if ($node->type == 'car') {
      if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_price') {
        $variables['items']['0']['#markup'] = $new_value; //new value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check here: http://tassaf.moriamedia.com/change-field-value-in-node-view/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.